# How can I explicitly change the RowState of an ADO.Net DataRow?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Given an ADO.Net `DataRow`, how I can change the row's RowState from `Added` to `Modified` or `Deleted`?

I tried setting the property directly:

```
myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].RowState = DataViewRowState.ModifiedOriginal;
```

resulting in the following error message from the compiler:

```
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'DataRow.RowState' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: Did you tried **anything**? Show your effort first.. And please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: @SonerGönül sory i didn't mentioned. Yes i tried alot one of them is mentioned in question.

Comment: -1 *Not working* is an absolutely horrible description of the problem, whatever it is.

Comment: Use `Rows[0].SetAdded()` and `Rows[0].SetModified()` and `Rows[0].Delete()`

Comment: This question is a great example of overly-aggressive closure of a useful, answerable question. Someone with expertise recognized the issue and provided a response that has likely helped a few thousand people. Comments prompting the asker to provide more detail would have sufficed. Downvoting and voting to close didn't help anyone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Though there are methods for setting the `RowState` property explicitly, like `SetAdded`, `SetModified` and `Delete`, I think it's better to understand what exactly happens automatically.

If you need to set the `RowState` to unchanged, then call `AcceptChanges` on the row and go from there. If you need it to be in a modified state, and it's not currently, there's a good chance you should have called `AcceptChanges` on the `DataRow` or `DataTable` somewhere else in the logic - this way when you make modifications to the row via code like:

```
row["field"] = "New Value";
```

it changes the `RowState` to `Modified` but now it also has a baseline, the `Original` row state, because you had accepted the changes previously.

My point here is that, yes, you can set the `RowState` explicitly with a few of those methods, but I feel like you may just need to work with the ADO.NET interface a bit more like it was intended.